# Matlab's eigs not converging unless number of eigenvalues computed is large

Tags: matlab, math, eigenvalue

I am trying to compute the eigenvalues, λ (`lambda`), of a damped structure with the following equations of motion:

(λ²**M** + λ**C** + **K**) **x** = **0**,

where **M**, **C**, and **K** are sparse matrices. Using MATLAB's `polyeig` function works, but I would like to go to larger systems and take advantage of the sparsity of my matrices. I have used a state space linearization to obtain a generalized eigenvalue problem as follows:

(**A** - λ**B**) **z** = **0**,

with

**A** = [**K** , **0** ; **0**, -**M**],

**B** = [-**C** , -**M** ; -**M**, **0**],

**z** = [**x** ; λ**x**]

Solving this with MATLAB's `eigs` function:

```
lambda = eigs(A,B,10,'sm')
```

Produces the following output:

```
lambda =
   1.0e+03 *
  -0.2518 - 1.3138i
  -0.2518 + 1.3138i
  -0.4690 - 1.7360i
  -0.4690 + 1.7360i
  -0.4690 - 1.7360i
  -0.4690 + 1.7360i
  -0.5387 - 1.8352i
  -0.5387 + 1.8352i
      NaN +    NaNi
      NaN +    NaNi
```

The first eight eigenvalues are correct, but it seems as though the last two eigenvalues were not able to converge. Increasing the number of Lanczos basis vectors does not seem to improve the problem.

Strangely however, increasing the number of eigenvalues computed (`k`) allows more and more eigenvalues to converge:

- `k =  10`:      Number of lambdas converged = 8
- `k =  20`:      Number of lambdas converged = 8
- `k =  50`:      Number of lambdas converged = 8
- `k = 100`:      Number of lambdas converged = 20
- `k = 120`:      Number of lambdas converged = 80
- `k = 150`:      Number of lambdas converged = 150

It may also be worth mentioning that many of the eigenvalues that do not converge with lower values of `k` appear to be degenerate or at least very closely spaced.

I was wondering if anybody can think of an explanation for this behavior? If so, is there any way to make all of the eigenvalues converge without making `k` very large? Thank you!

Comment: Interesting problem and highly coherent question; I wish every single one was this well-formed! Welcome to Stack Overflow, and kudos:)

Comment: How close to symmetric are `M`, `C`, and `K`?

Comment: The matrices are all symmetric (theoretically as well as numerically).

Comment: @DimitriK is this question still unsolved and relevant? I'm thinking of posting a small bounty on this question, but only in case that's useful to you. And in case you'll be able to respond to queries in the week while the bounty lasts.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer, but I can't comment yet. Your matrices A and B seem to be symmetric, so according to [this](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node54.html), Your eigenvalues should be real but the ones you computed are complex. Could you upload your code and matrices?

Comment: I agree, it's difficult to say what is happening without looking at the matrices. Any way, this question is very interesting!

Comment: Condition of infinity usually happens, when you have zero entries. You can directly solve that part to obtain a result. Its messy however, if you do not handle this automatically.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, but does this [tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48-lobpcg-m) satisfy your needs?

Comment: @multigrid101 i've seen this kind of problem before and in that case the matrices were complex and symmetric. A propery that is hard to exploit.

Comment: @DimitriK I know the performance of the QZ algorithm in LAPACK (and consequently the polyeig method) is quite poor. If B is invertible, would computing the dense eigencomposition of the linearized equation satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but still unanswered. Without the actual matrices it is difficult to be certain. This is my best guess:

`eigs` calls ARPACK routines. ARPACK exploits iterative methods (Arnoldi) to converge to, e.g., the eigenvalues with smallest magnitude (option `sm`). As for any iterative method, the user can specify options like the convergence `Tolerance` and the `MaxIterations` before the iterative process stops. The `NaN`s indicate eigenvalues that have not converged when `MaxIterations` is reached.

An important option for Arnoldi methods is the dimension of the Krylov subspace used to approximate the solutions. This can be specified by the option `SubspaceDimension` in `eigs`. The default value is max(2*k,20), so increasing `k` effectively increases the dimension of the Krylov subspace. If your problem requires a relatively large Krylov subspace for converging some eigenvalues to the desired `Tolerance`, this could explain why increasing `k` yields convergence of a larger number of eigenvalues.

To verify if my guess is correct you could either have a less restrictive `Tolerance` (`e-6` may be sufficient?) or increase the value of `SubspaceDimension` while keeping `k` constant.